# Question regarding speed of causality and speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, causality

Recently I came across a question regarding to why the speed of light and the speed of causality are the same. Link-[Why is the speed of causality equal to the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529470/236793)
I came up with an explanation, but I am not sure if it is right.
I thought that we could say that the cause travels in such a way that it must not experience any time i.e. the proper time for the cause travelling must be zero, which by special relativity is when something travels at the speed of light. Is there any possibility of this being a proper explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Causality and light do not necessarily have the same speed, but causality cannot exceed the speed of light in a vacuum. Since light and gravity cannot exceed c, then an action could not cause a reaction before it could be seen, felt, or known to have happened. Causality can, however, travel slower than c. Some force transmissions propagate at a medium or object's speed of sound, which is considerably less than c.