# Exceeding the speed of light in view of special theory of relativity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers, faster-than-light

**Is there any rigorous way to show that it is impossible to have any inertial reference frame with the speed of light apart from the blow up of the Lorentz factor?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595605/2451

Comment: The only vectors orthogonal to a lightlike vector are multiples of itself.